# autoplay delay keyframes

Tags: flash, delay, autoplay, flex-mx

Code below is for my slideshow in FlashMX. I've gotten autoplay to work. However, I can't seem to get the delay between keyframes to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

`function updateFrame (inc) {
    // send slides to new frame
    newFrame = _root._currentFrame + inc;
    _root.gotoAndStop(newFrame);

```
updateStatus();

if (_root._currentFrame == 1) {
    prevBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
} else {
    prevBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
}
if (_root._currentFrame == _root._totalFrames) {
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
} else {
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
}
}function updateStatus () {
_root.statusField = _root._currentFrame + " of " + _root._totalFrames;
} function autoplayInit () {
startTime = getTimer();
hideControls();
updateStatus();
}function autoplay () {
if (autoplayStatus != 0) {
    // get the current time and elapsed time
    curTime = getTimer();
    elapsedTime = curTime-startTime;

    // update timer indicator
    indicatorFrame = int(4/(delay/(elapsedTime/1000)));
    indicator.gotoAndStop(indicatorFrame+1);

    // if delay time if met, goto next photo
    if (elapsedTime >= (delay*1000)) {
        if (_root._currentframe == _root._totalframes) {
            _root.gotoAndStop(1);
        } else {
            _root.nextFrame();
        }
        autoplayInit();
    }
}
}function hideControls () {
nextBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
prevBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
}updateFrame();
autoplayStatus = 0;'
```